# Is the composition of two quasi-affine morphisms quasi-affine?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Recall a morphism $f:X \to Y$ is quasi-affine if the inverse image of any affine open in $Y$ is quasi-affine.

> Is the composition of two quasi-affine morphisms quasi-affine?

The only reference I can find is from the Stacks Project, but the proof of the statement is omitted.

Comment: This appears to be in [EGA II.5](https://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/math256-fall13-spring14/EGAII-5.pdf), though Grothendieck uses a slightly different definition.

Comment: It is Lemma 28.13.4 from the [Stacks project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01SJ) (on this page the proof is not omitted, oddly).